# Put semicolon in sql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I would like to know if i can put a semicolon in a SQL table.
Or would that mess things up like an injection attack.
Basically what I'm trying to put in is my HTTP_USER_AGENT info and that includes a semicolon.
Or Basically there a way i can turn that semicolon into the html symbol for it?
Thank You So Much

Comment: You need to read up on injection, examples and how to avoid them - it sounds like you've heard about it but don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: On a related not: Using *prepared statements* will escape the input values properly without manual intervention from your side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can put a semicolon in a mySQL table. Even more: You can put anything into it as long as it is [escaped](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) properly.

However, I'd heavily recommend using prepared statements that will do the escaping for you. My first preference is [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepare.php) but you can also check out [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I think what actually happens is that the way they pass the parameters in makes escaping unnecessary.  When you prepare a statement, the database engine turns this into an execution plan, which is typically a binary structure.  I expect what typically happens is that the execution plan links into the parameter dictionary, which is also a binary structure.

Answer (score -1):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), it will do all the escaping work for you, you just have to put ' before and after it.

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
```

Comment: No, manual escaping of strings will cause your application to be much more complicated and still have security holes. Use parameterised queries throughout.

Comment: Does the PHP MySQL driver finally support parameterized queries? I cannot find anything related on http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Comment: Oh, and please explain what security holes mysql_real_escape_string has when used everywhere and surrounded with '-